# Socket Exception: Connection Actively refused

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

Currently making a vb.net program to communicate a string between two computers.  My test bed is a Windows 8 machine connecting to a windows 7 VM.  However, despite numerous measures, I still continue getting this error on the development machine side.  Here is what I've done/enabled so far.

- Running main program within debugger in visual studio, connecting to
  deployed program in test VM
- Port 61337.  IP addresses are unique to each machine.
- Bridged connection
- Firewall is down in Test VM
- Firewall Connection Rule in Development machine allows any tcp
  connection across any endpoint across any port
- Netgear router has port forwarding enabled across the above port to the development machine.

I've been racking my brain and can't seem to think of anything else I haven't tried at this point.

Is there anything I'm missing?  I suspect it's something really obvious.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Edit: Here is how I've configured the block for the host machine(the vm in this scenario).  It was taken from someone's c# version from a blog.

```
Dim LocalHostName As String = Dns.GetHostName()
Dim LocalHostIPEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(LocalHostName)
Dim LocalHostIP As IPAddress = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList(0)
Dim LocalIPEndPointAnyIP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(LocalHostIP, _Port)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely binding to and listening on a loopback interface. Use [`IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) instead of `LocalHostIP` to accept connections on *any* interface.

Comment: ....yeah I figured it was something really obvious. :)  What I hadn't realized from earlier answers was that "127.0.0.1" and the ip address of the server is treated as the same.  I had also thought that was what I was supposed to do, for some reason.  Re-reading the MSDN entry for TcpListener..., yeah I'm now feeling really silly.  Anyways, thanks again!